# AWS SAM: Could not install from function as it does not contain a package.json file

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm using AWS SAM in Visual Studio Code to set up a number of Node.js lambda functions. I am using Windows 10. I'm only starting out with AWS SAM and I've generated the Sample Hello World App using the Command Palette and it works. I started expanding the app by adding a second function and restructured the directory structure to start adding more functions. My directory structure now looks as follows:

```
|--my-app
|  |--event-handlers
|  |  |--hello-world
|  |  |  |--app.js
|  |  |--hello-world-2
|  |  |  |--app.js
|  |--package.json
|  |--template.yml
```

When I run `sam build` I get the error **Could not install from ..\my-app\event-handlers\hello-world as it does not contain a package.json file**. If I copy my package.json file into each of the subdirectories *hello-world* and *hello-world-2* then `sam build` works fine. But it doesn't seem right that I need to specify a separate package.json file for each function because it breaks DRY principles. I was expecting that it should use the package.json from the root directory for all my lambda functions if I structure it like this.

Do I really need to duplicate the package.json file for each lambda function? What are best practices in terms of a directory structure for a SAM application that defines multiple lambda functions? Why is it not picking up my package.json file from my root directory?

For reference I am including a section of my template.yaml file too

```
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function 
    Properties:
      CodeUri: event-handlers/hello-world/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        HelloWorld:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /hello
            Method: get

  HelloWorldFunction2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: event-handlers/hello-world-2/
      Handler: app.lambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Events:
        MyScheduledEvent:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Schedule: rate(2 minutes)
            Name: app.lambdaHandler
            Description: Interval at which node function should be called
            Enabled: True
```

Comment: this seems to be required as part of `sam build`. it can be an empty file. or just avoid using `sam build` if you don't need it

Comment: I tried using an empty file, but it requires a json format in the file. So then I made it empty {} but then it starts doing validations and gives error "NPM Failed: npm ERR! package.json requires a "name" field" etc. Which means I have to duplicate the "required" fields from the main json file in the root to all the sub-functions...which brings me back to my original problem. It doesn't feel like the correct approach to duplicate the files, but like a misconfiguration of some sort that the higher-level file is not picked up for all the sub-functions.

Answer (score 2):

Each lambda is deployed with its own dependency stack. In most of the cases I've encountered, this is a good thing. Two lambdas with exactly the same dependencies indicates duplicated functionality or unused dependencies in one of the functions.

I'm getting the same error as you are, but because I *don't* have a `package.json` in the root folder. The `hello-world` sample project generated with `sam init` doesn't have one in the root folder either, but somehow `sam build` has no problem building that.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue.

What fixed it is moving the package.json one level down i.e

[image]

In short, you should always stick to the below diagram for building your SAM project correctly

[image]

Answer (score 2):

specify the location on package.json with --manifest:

sam build --template template.yaml --manifest package.json

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had to remove the **CodeUri** property from my serverless function. Even though the path looked correct, the *sam build* command failed witht he above message.